# Why doesn't my use of Google Maps' panTo() method or directions work?

Tags: json, google-maps

I am having problems with centering the map using the `panTo()` method - as well as making the directions (from/to) to work like tabs.

Here is my code:

http://dpaste.com/76251/

Comment: Might help if you described the specific problem you're having and quoted the relevant code. You also may wish to ask two separate questions (one regarding panTo, one regarding directions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example snippet you're linking to is no longer available, but assuming from the answer by Chris, I'm assuming you want to center the marker whose info window was opened. I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'infowindowopen', function() {
    map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what you want the map to do, but there is one big problem with your `panTo()` function.  You placed it inside of the function `markerClickHandler()` which is called when the markers are created, which happens on page load.  So you are calling `panTo()` three times when the page is loaded.

If you want it to be called when the marker is clicked, place it in the function which is returned by `markerClickHandler()`.

Keep in mind, however, that the movement will likely be interrupted by the opening of the Info Window (which moves the map).  The best solution I can think of to that problem is to *move the map after the window has opened*.  You can pass [onOpenFn](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions.onOpenFn) as a GInfoWindowOptions parameter:

```
map.openInfoWindowTabsHtml(marker.getLatLng(), tabs, {
    onOpenFn: function() {
        map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
    }
});
```

Note: for some reason, this only worked if I called `openInfoWindowTabsHtml()` on the map object instead of the marker - I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Just to clarify things I would like to pan the map when a user clicks on any of the items in the side navigation.

Comment: No problem - let me know if you have any other issues.